# How to add edge weights in ent?

Tags: go, graph-databases

I'm trying to use `ent` to build a recommendation engine (https://entgo.io/docs/schema-def/) by essentially treating ent over MySQL the same a Gremlin over a GraphDB.

I cannot figure out if there is a canonical way to add edge weights to the pre-generated schemas in `ent`. I think I could roll my own by modifying the generated code, but I feel like there must be a builtin way to generate edge weights, its not exactly an uncommon requirement.

How can I add weights or, generally, value data to edges in `ent`?